# Django formset for models without foreign key

Tags: django, neo4j, django-forms, formset, neomodel

I'm trying to use `formset` to create connections between my Neo4j nodes. These models have been constructed using the django-neomodel package. They aren't related using foreign keys, but since this *isn't* an `inline formset` that shouldn't matter, right?

**models.py**

```
class Person(DjangoNode):
  uid = UniqueIdProperty()
  name = StringProperty(max_length=50)
  created_at = DateTimeProperty(default=datetime.now)

  friends = RelationshipTo('Friend', 'FRIENDED', model=FriendRel)

  # DjangoNode class must have a Meta class and documentation specifies 'django_node'
  class Meta:
    app_label = 'django_node'


class FriendRel(DjangoRel):
  created_at = DateTimeProperty(default=datetime.now)

  class Meta:
    app_label = 'django_rel'
```

**forms.py**

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    # don't need fields for automatically assigned keys like `uid` and `created_at`
    fields = ['name']


class FriendRelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta: 
    model = FriendRel
    exclude = () #"creating ModelForm without either 'fields' || 'exclude' attribute is prohibited"

FriendRelFormSet = formset_factory(FriendRelForm, extra=1)
```

**form.html**

```
<div>
  <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <table class="table">
      {{ friends.management_form }}

      {% for form in friends.forms %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
          </thead>
        {% endif %}
        <tr class="{% cycle "row1" "row2" %} formset_row">
          {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <td>
              <!-- Include the hidden fields in the form -->
              {% if forloop.first %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                  {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
              {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
              {{ field }}
            </td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm expecting a "friend" formset to appear in the rendered form, but am not quite sure how to get it there. If I add the following I get an error:

```
  class FriendRelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
      model = FriendRel
      exclude = ()
      fields = ['friends']

***ERROR*** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (friends) specified for FriendRel
```